# Message-ID in Gmail Add-on is blank

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-addons

I'm writing a Gmail add-on using Apps Script and want to get access to the header property Message-ID. The documentation states I can do this by using message.getHeader("Message-ID"), however it comes back as blank. I thought I would then try and manually parse it from the raw message, but when I view what is returned from message.getRawContent(), the Message-ID property has it's value removed. Similarly the In-Reply-To property is also blank. When I contrast this to what I see when I click on the Show Original option in Gmail these values are there.

I thought it might be something to do with not having permission to view that property, but I can't find a scope that makes it available.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized the problem was that the Message-ID was being returned, but it couldn't be displayed because it comes back in the format "<CAAsNV5rAkRGiw5AnhcikB4kNNY8r5SF+VGwpq9MufwVsVRkfzw@mail.gmail.com>", which it assumes is an HTML tag. So just removing the front and end characters fixes my issue.